# Jboss AS 7.1.1 default httpclient 4.1.2 was used instead of my maven depency Httpclient 4.5.2

Tags: java, jboss, dependencies, httpclient

Jboss 7.1.1 default httpclient 4.1.2 was used instead of my maven depency Httpclient 4.5.2:

Now I'm having a conflict and I can't load the org.apache.http.conn.ssl.* at runtime

because it doesnt exist in httpclient 4.1.2 of the jboss module.

I tried the solution of jboss-deployment-structure.xml and put it in any possible part of the project but still it doesnt work. It is supposed to be preventing to load implicitly the httpclient 4.1.2 from my module class.

stucked :/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating the jar files of httpcomponent -> main modules of jboss folder.

still don't know why my ear application calls jboss libraries instead of its own maven libraries.